# Using multiple sub ordinating conjunction in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, conjunction, standard-german

> Ich ärgere mich, dass ich nichts kaufen kann, weil die Geschäfte geschlossen sind.
>   I am upset that I could buy nothing because the shops were closed.
>
> Ich habe eine Überraschung  für dich geplant, weil ich es weiß, dass du die Überraschung magst.
>   I have a surprise for you because I know you like surprises.

In these sentences I have used two conjunction in a same sentence. My teacher said that this is not valid grammar. I can only use only one such conjunction. The remaining sentence must start separately after the period.
Like this:

> Ich ärgere mich, dass ich nichts kaufen kann. Weil die Geschäfte geschlossen sind.

Although this structure sounds reasonable enough, I think the my sentences above are also grammatically valid. And as to using multiple subordinating conjunction or any other conjunction , I believe it is ok to use as much of those required by the sentence.

I would like to know about this one in detail. If there are actually rules that enforces limitations on the number of conjunctions one is allowed to use in a sentence.
Any grammar rule on this or any comments and suggestions to my sentences above would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: "dass du die Überraschung magst" is not how native speakers of German would say this. The typical expression would be (in the context you gave): "... dass du Überraschungen magst". This is because it is supposed that the person likes Überraschungen in principle, not the specific one that is now going to be reveiled. You use "der/die/das" on subjects that are supposed to be already known to the participants of the communication (i.e. introduced into the communication earlier).

Comment: Interesting by the way where your teacher took his (misleading) idea from. Any information on the setting of your learning? Meaning: where are you?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am from Nepal. I am currently enrolled in A2 level.

Comment: And the teacher is... a local? A German?

Comment: No, he is not. He lived in Germany for few years though.

Comment: Your teacher may be under the impression of the **English** *no run-on sentences* rule. This rule does not apply to German. In contrary, German writers use commas and full stops distinctively to group and separate thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your teacher is wrong. Your sentences are more correct than

> Ich ärgere mich, dass ich nichts kaufen kann. Weil die Geschäfte geschlossen sind.

The latter is actually grammatically flawed. However, it might be used to emphasize the importance of the last subclause. But this is rather the sort of language you would expect either in a novel or in advertisment, not in a normal use of german language.

Actually, german is famous (or rather infamous) for its long sentences assembled of multiple subclauses. There is a limit of understandability which marks the border of good style - which anyway is not crossed in your example sentences. But from a mere grammatical point of view, this is totally fine.

There are some german writers and philosophers which are known for writing long and complex, hardly understandable sentences such as Thomas Mann, Immanuel Kant and Theodor W. Adorno.

A famous example is a sentence which is said to be the longest sentence in the opus of Thomas Mann, from *Joseph und seine Brüder* (from the volume *Geschichten Jaakobs*, chapter *Der junge Joseph*):

> Der junge Joseph zum Beispiel, Jaakobs Sohn und der lieblichen,
>   zu früh gen Westen gegangenen Rahel, Joseph zu seiner
>   Zeit, als Kurigalzu, der Kossäer, zu Babel saß, Herr der vier
>   Gegenden, König von Schumir und Akkad, höchst wohltuend dem Herzen
>   Bel-Marudugs, ein zugleich strenger und üppiger Gebieter,
>   dessen Bartlöckchen so künstlich gereiht erschienen, daß sie
>   einer Abteilung gut ausgerichteter Schildträger glichen; - zu
>   Theben aber, in dem Unterlande, das Joseph 'Mizraim' oder auch
>   'Keme, das Schwarze', zu nennen gewohnt war, seine Heiligkeit
>   der gute Gott, genannt 'Amun ist zufrieden' und dieses Namens
>   der dritte, der Sonne leiblicher Sohn, zum geblendeten Entzücken
>   der Staubgeborenen im Horizont seines Palastes strahlte; als
>   Assur zunahm durch die Kraft seiner Götter und auf der großen
>   Straße am Meere, von Gaza hinauf zu den Pässen des Zederngebirges,
>   königliche Karawanen Höflichkeitskontributionen in Lapislazuli
>   und gestempeltem Golde zwischen den Höfen des Landes der
>   Ströme und dem Pharaoàs hin und her führten; als man in den
>   Städten der Amoriter zu Beth-San, Ajalon, Taàanek, Urusalim der
>   Aschtarti diente, zu Sichem und Beth-Lahama das siebentägige
>   Klagen um den Wahrhaften Sohn, den Zerrissenen, erscholl und zu
>   Gebal, der Buchstadt, El angebetet ward, der keines Tempels und
>   Kultus bedurfte: Joseph also, wohnhaft im Distrikte Kenana des
>   Landes, das ägyptisch das Obere Retenu hieß, in seines Vaters
>   von Terebinthen und immergrünen Steineichen beschattetem Familienlager
>   bei Hebron, ein berühmt angenehmer Jüngling, angenehm
>   namentlich in erblicher Nachfolge seiner Mutter, die hübsch und
>   schön gewesen war wie der Mond, wenn er voll ist, und wie Ischtars
>   Stern, wenn er milde im Reinen schwimmt, außerdem aber, vom
>   Vater her, ausgestattet mit Geistesgaben, durch welche er diesen
>   wohl gar in gewissem Sinne noch übertraf, - Joseph denn schließlich
>   (zum fünften- und sechstenmal nennen wir seinen Namen und
>   mit Befriedigung; denn um den Namen steht es geheimnisvoll, und
>   uns ist, als gäbe sein Besitz uns Beschwörerkraft über des Knaben
>   zeitversunkene, doch einst so gesprächig-lebensvolle Person)
>   - Joseph für sein Teil erblickte in einer südbabylonischen Stadt
>   namens Uru, die er in seiner Mundart 'Ur Kaschdim', 'Ur der Chaldäer' zu nennen pflegte, den Anfang aller, das heißt: seiner
>   persönlichen Dinge.

This is intentionally crossing the border of readability. It is thus not an example of how you should write your sentences, because it is used to create a certain tone of complexity, vagueness, non-understandability and irony, which is used as a matter of style (to express the distance of the current reader to Joseph). **But grammatically it is correct.**

For more on the *stylist* aspect, also see this article from [Die ZEIT](https://www.zeit.de/2012/20/Lektion-15-Saetze-Satzlaenge) on the length of sentences.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that these sentences in German literature achieve their length not by nesting but by adding clauses on the same level. Truly deeply nested sentences are rare even in German literature.

Comment: An example for nested conjunctions from a German law text (§ 432 German civil code): Jeder Gläubiger kann verlangen, dass der Schuldner die geschuldete Sache für alle Gläubiger hinterlegt oder, wenn sie sich nicht zur Hinterlegung eignet, an einen gerichtlich zu bestellenden Verwahrer abliefert.

Comment: Well, the example of Thomas Mann is a mixture of subclauses and main-clauses.

Comment: Indeed a famous example.